# how to get html content of a page that expands dynamically

Tags: php

I am able to get the html content of a normal page using php.
But I intend to get the content of a page that grows dynamically (like in facebook) as you scroll down. How should I aim to get the content of such a page ?

Thanks!

Comment: Vague question. How are you trying to "get" it?

Comment: You should check [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to easily handle such behavior

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Facebook etc use a form of lazy fetching, meaning that they only fetch an X amount of posts in batches. You won't be able to scrape a webpage if the content isn't printed to that page. The only way you can get that content is by communicating with the database, by using an available API, or by using language related functions like: `http://url/page.ext?data=X&user=Y` or at last by using javascript events.